# count number of rows for each subgroup over dynamic time period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table:

```
userId,  date,       sessionID
1234     2020-01-10  dsfdstre
5678     2020-01-15  dxfgfgh
9101     2020-01-20  3cvdfgf
1213     2020-01-25  sdfyu
```

This is only an illustration of my table. What's important here is that a user can have multiple sessions over time.

What I want to achieve is bucketing my user based on the number of sessions. In other words grouping all users with 10 and more sessions, users with 5 - 10 sessions, users with less than 5 sessions etc... I want the count of sessions to occurs on the selected time period (with a slicer of something similar.

Ideally I want to achieve this using dax.

I've tested a lot of formula, nothing is working correctly. I'm kind of lost at this point. Any idea?

Comment: *"I've tested a lot of formula, nothing is working correctly. I'm kind of lost at this point. Any idea?"*. How about showing the formulae you tested?

Comment: Why don't you add a column with expected results to your table?